# Use THREE.LoadingMAnager() to load the materials for a THREE.BoxGeometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, loading

I'm trying to update the image asset on a geometry after user interaction, basically loading low res assets to begin with and swapping to high res assets when the user interacts with it.
If I just use standard code like below:

```
var materials = [
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/0.jpg' )  }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/1.jpg' )  }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/2.jpg' )  }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/3.jpg' )  }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/4.jpg' )  }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:loader.load('assets/object/5.jpg' )  }),
]; 
target.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
var texture = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
target.material = texture;
```

The low res assets are cleared from the geometry showing the base colour, the high-res assets take a second to load and then appear on the geometry.

I need to load the assets and then swap them, and from some reading it seems like THREE.LoadingManager() is the way to go, however I'm a bit lost.

So far this is what I have but it's throwing errors....

```
var textureManager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
textureManager.onProgress = function ( item, loaded, total ) {
    console.log(item+' = '+loaded / total * 100) + '%';
};
textureManager.onLoad = function () {
    console.log(' loading complete');

    var materials = [
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[0] }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[1] }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[2] }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[3] }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[4] }),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map:myTextureArray[5] })
    ]; 
    target.children[i].material.materials.map.needsUpdate = true;
    var texture = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    target.children[i].material = texture;
};

var textureLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader( textureManager );
myTextureArray = [];
var myTexture = new THREE.Texture();

myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/0.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/1.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/2.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/3.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/4.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
myTextureArray.push(   textureLoader.load( 'assets/objtect1/hires/5.jpg', function ( image ) { myTexture.image = image; } )  );
```

Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone else, the problem was that I was using the ImageLoader, not TextureLoader.

Replace:

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader( textureManager );
```

With

```
var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader( textureManager );
```